# Problems encountered when building the spring boot 2.2.9. RELEASE source environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When I execute `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pfast`,then this error has occurred

Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin:1.4.2:wget (unpack-doc-resources) on project spring-boot-gradle-plugin: IO Error: Could not get content -> [Help 1]

i have tried `mvn clean -rf :spring-boot-gradle-plugin` but it didn't work

Comment: Hi there, please provide source code to reproduce your issue~

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I deleted the spring boot gradle plugin project, modified the pom.xml in the spring boot tools project, removed this module, and re executed the `mvn clean install DSkipTests Pfast`. The problem was resolved